# Maps Update Degraded Off-Route Traffic Display

Tags: updates, google-maps-navigation

I've been using Google Maps Navigation to help with my commute for about 2 years now.  One common action that I take is to start Naviation to my destination, and then look at the traffic display on other interstates to see if there's a quicker route.

The last update to navigation changed the display so that the red/yellow/green traffic overlays over the orangish/brownish roads are thinner, making it much harder to see the off-route traffic.  Also, the off-route map stays "light" even when I move the map around with my finger, exacerbating the problem -- it used to not do that as well.

I'm currently working around the issue by uninstalling the last update, but

1. Is there a way to fix the issue without unintalling the latest update?
2. Is there a way to give google feedback so that they fix the issue in future versions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one has answered my question, so I will share what I've learned with my own investigation.

1. No, you have to uninstall updates from the manage apps menu selection from the home screen.  I'm currently doing this as a workaround.
2. I didn't find a way to email google and get an answer, but I did find their forums.  The related question on their forums is at

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=0d337324bcc86a55&hl=en&fid=0d337324bcc86a550004b349bee9f864

There has been particiption in the discussion from a google employee, which is a good sign.  Also, version 6.0.0 is an improvement of 5.12.0, but still not as good as 5.8.0.